# Can web bluetooth be supported in vs code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, bluetooth, electron, vscode-extensions, web-bluetooth

I am trying to develop a **vs code extension** that needs Bluetooth interaction with ble devices.

I know **vs code** built on top of **electron** and electron supports web bluetooth api ([blog related to this](https://dev.to/manufac/using-web-bluetooth-in-an-electron-app-in-2022-4f69)).

Also, I tested in VS Code chrome DevTools the web Bluetooth API (navigator.bluetooth) is working.

when i tried to use web bluetooth in webview of vs code i am getting cors error (ofcourse as webview in vscode are simply iframes)

```
SecurityError: requestDevice() called from cross-origin iframe
```

at the end using [**noble**](https://github.com/noble/noble) library to work but i just managed to get it work on **windows**. on **linux** it will not work as the node build that sits inside VS Code need permission to access Bluetooth. **mac** also getting many problems.

Things will be easier if some how I can use web Bluetooth directly within vs code extension but vs code doesn't let you use electron APIs.

**UPDATE 2023/04/28:**
managed with [abandonware/noble](https://github.com/abandonware/noble)
now working on mac and windows
its open source for brilliant labs
here the [link](https://github.com/brilliantlabsAR/ar-studio-for-vscode)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: Support for using Web Bluetooth from cross-origin iframes was added to Chromium 104, which is when that error message was removed. If the version of VSCode you're using is using an older version Electron then it won't work. This is something that needs to first be supported by VSCode by granting the iframe where the extension runs permission to use Web Bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ReillyGrant , 
yes you are right my current vscode uses electron '19.1.11' and it needs atleast 20.0.0 to support chromium 104. so i guess have to wait for next updates from vscode